# Store PDF file to nodejs filesystem

Tags: node.js, mongoose

I have a **post route** which saves all the data and then it has PDF file but now I want to save it to the fs but it gives an error

```
The "path" argument must be one of type string, Buffer, or URL. Received type object
```

here is the model
**report.js**

```
  name:String,
    age:Number,
    customerDetails:String,
    userReport:{
    user:String,
    reportDate:String, 
    pdf:{
    data:Buffer,
    contentType:Schema.Types.Mixed
    }
}
```

on **api.js**

```
const fs = require('fs');
const util = require('util');
const readFile = util.promisify(fs.readFile);
router.post("api/report",async(req,res) =>{
let rep = new Report({
name:req.body.name,
age:req.body.age,
customerDetails:req.body.customerDetails,
userReport:req.body.userReport
});
await readFile(req.body.userReport, function(err,data){
 if (err) {
      console.log(err)
    } else {

      rep.userReport.pdf.data = data;
      rep.userReport.pdf.contentType = 'application/pdf';

      rep
        .save()
        .then(result => {
          return res.status(200).json({
            result: result
          });
    })
  })
}
```

Comment: Are you using any middleware such as multer ?

Comment: What's the value of `req.body.userReport`?

Comment: Have not used it yet. but I am not sure how would it help.. my post request goes to angular app

Comment: yes it is an object and my guess is that problem occurs on await readFile

Comment: because I want to get pdf data and save it on file system

Comment: anyone? I have tried to `JSON.stringify(req.body.userReport)`